# How do I enable double-buffering of a control using C# (Windows forms)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, doublebuffered, ownerdrawn

How do I enable double-buffering of a control using C# (Windows forms)?

I have a panel control which I am drawing stuff into and also an owner-drawn tab control. Both suffer from flicker, so how can I enable double-buffering?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the constructor of your control, set the DoubleBuffered property, and/or ControlStyle appropriately.

For example, I have a simple DoubleBufferedPanel whose constructor is the following:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | 
              ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
              ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
              ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
              ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
              ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor
              , true);
```

Comment: simply doing the this.DoubleBuffered = true; is generally enough, good answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

some info here:

[How to double buffer .NET controls on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form)

Answer (score -2):

Use the DoubleBuffered property, inherited from the System.Windows.Forms.Control.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form myForm = new System.Windows.forms.Form();
myForm.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, the DoubleBuffered property is protected. The op has probably checked the public properties before putting the question.