# How to fix panel flickering when redrawing?

Tags: c#, panel

I have a panel that I've subclassed to and have set `DoubleBuffered` true, I constantly need to refresh the drawing but it flickers and have no idea why.

```
private delegate void MyDelegate();

public void heartBeat()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (map.processNubots(rules))
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    this.Invoke((MyDelegate)delegate
                    {
                        //drawPanel.SuspendLayout();
                        drawPanel.Refresh();
                        displayGrid();
                        //drawPanel.ResumeLayout();
                    });
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void displayGrid()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry pair in map)
        {
            Monomer current = (Monomer)pair.Value;
            drawMonomers(current.getLocation(), current.getState());
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void drawMonomers(Point location, string state)
    {
        ...

        SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(mycolor);
        SolidBrush sbt = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        Graphics g = drawPanel.CreateGraphics();
        Font text = new Font("Arial", scale / 2);
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
        g.FillEllipse(sb, offSet + ((location.Y * scale) / 2) + (location.X * scale), offSet + (-location.Y * scale), scale, scale);
        g.DrawEllipse(pen, offSet + ((location.Y * scale) / 2) + (location.X * scale), offSet + (-location.Y * scale), scale, scale);
        g.DrawString(state, text, sbt, (offSet + ((location.Y * scale) / 2) + (location.X * scale)) + scale / 6, (offSet + (-location.Y * scale)) + scale / 6);

        sb.Dispose();
        sbt.Dispose();
        pen.Dispose();
    }
```

So after every "computation" and have added something to my imaginary grid, I need to update the panel to show this new item on my grid. I have tried invalidating the panel right before the `displayGrid()` function but it seems to cause even more flickering.

The `heartbeat()` function is currently being called on a separate thread.

Here is my new `Panel` class.

```
public class Display : Panel
{
    public Display()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: does every elipse change every computation?

Comment: No it doesn't, however, at this point I'm redrawing all of them. I do need to make a future optimization of only changing what needs to be updated. But it starts flickering maybe on the 20th or so ellipse and that seems to soon to be related to that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    Graphics g = drawPanel.CreateGraphics();
```

Using CreateGraphics() *and* turning on double-buffering is the worst possible combination.  CreateGraphics() gives you a Graphics object that draws directly to the screen.  Double-buffering sets up a Graphics object that draws to a bitmap, the buffer used in double-buffering.  Then renders the bitmap to the screen at the end of the paint cycle.

So what happens in your code is that you draw the screen directly, something you can barely see but visible if it is slow enough.  Then right after that the buffer that you never draw into gets painted.  Which wipes out what you drew before.  The net effect is **heavy** flicker with your paint output visible for only a handful of milliseconds.

Using CreateGraphics() was the mistake.  You *always* want to render through the e.Graphics object that you get from the Paint event so you'll render to the buffer.  Pass that Graphics object to your drawMonomers() method.  Thus:

```
public void drawMonomers(Graphics g, Point location, string state) {
   // Etc...
}

private void Display1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
   //...
   drawMonomers(e.Graphics, loc, state);
}
```

In general, CreateGraphics() has *very* limited usefulness.  You only ever use it when you *want* to draw to the screen directly and you can afford for whatever you draw to disappear.  That is typically only useful in the kind of program that has a render loop that constantly runs, producing new output at a high rate like 20+ frames per second.  Like a video game.

Comment: In my program I must compute some interactions before I drawMonomers, how would I be able to keep processing, then redrawing using this method?

Comment: Store whatever you compute in fields of your class so you'll have them readily available when it is time to paint.  If that computation hasn't completed yet then don't call drawMonomers() yet.  Call the panel's Invalidate() method as soon as that's done.

Comment: this computation is looping. compute objects in grid -> paint, compute objects in grid -> paint. As I understand the Paint is only done when it first loads the panel.

Comment: Painting is done when required.  Or when you force it, like you did in your code snippet by calling Refresh().

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing the Panel with a PictureBox. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Adding the AllPaintingInWmPaint style will prevent the background from being redrawn.

I've run across this post before and found it quite helpful.  [How do I enable double-buffering of a control using C# (Windows forms)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220100/how-do-i-enable-double-buffering-of-a-control-using-c-sharp-window-forms)

It *might* be overkill, but it works.  One thing I've noticed with users is, if it *appears* to be running smoother and faster it *is*.  (even if it really does take a little longer)