# I have a picture box with an image without background but it only takes the color of the form as background

Tags: c#, forms, picturebox

I'm doing the table game battleship, by moving pictures boxes with the mouse, the problem is that all the picture boxes that I have contain an image without background, but i have the problem that when I move it through different points, it shows a default background instead of showing the background of the "map". This messes the aspect of the game table.

I've tried this code in my program ,but it makes the ships default position is in the panel(which I do not want) and it doesn't solve the problem I described earlier (when you move ships over the others spaces)

```
Barco1.Parent = panel1;
Barco1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

[image: This is the program working, here we see that one of the ships is on the table but the background is the one from the form]

[An example of one of the ships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKsOq.png)

Comment: pictures are png?

Comment: Yes, all of them

Comment: ok and you confirm they have transparency

Comment: Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910172/how-to-make-picturebox-transparent

Comment: There is no concept of one control being "behind" another in Winforms.  They are all siblings and the form is the parent, so that is what shows.

Comment: But this could be done to all the pictureboxes (I mean that first one for example with the other 3 and the panel), and while I'm moving it?

Comment: That is  how 'transparency' in winforms work: By faking it by coping the parent's surface..But Pbox is no container so you need code to make it thw parent of a a control: control.Parent = pbox; control.Location = ... - But: Do the images really have a transparent background? Can you post one?

Comment: I've done with Photoshop, but yes I'll post one

Comment: I've posted it on an edit

Comment: The image is fine indeed. Are you sure about the form color? for testing set form color to eg pink and report back. So the blue map is diplayed in panel1, right? I don't see you setting the location, btw.. This really ought to work! If it doesn't maybe some piece of code from testing messes things up..

Comment: In one comment you wrote 'moving though different pictureboxes'. What does that mean?? Explain your set up more clearly!!

Comment: That the other ships on the game are all pictureboxes, and if I pass through them, that it doesn't anything weird due to the background not being transparent

Comment: I am, putting starting points, maybe on the panel it's no fixed by code, only by the settings of the panel

Comment: In the my soution is to not use a panel, instead via photoshop I've puted the table exactly where I want in a png, and I use this image as background ,then the transparency works.

Answer (score 0):

[image: picture box with transparent image]

As you can see in the picture, there are:

- `Form` with a `BackgroundImage`,
- `Panel` with `BackColor = Color.Transparent` and `BackgroundImage = some-image`  and
- `PictureBox` with `BackColor = Color.Transparent` and an image as its `Image` property.

It should work for you.

Comment: But here there no transition of backgrounds which is what happens when i'm moving it with the mouse throught different pictures boxes

Comment: So there is rendering problem. try double-buffer the objects as described in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/220166/3764165

Answer (score -1):

It looks like You are setting the Image background as Transparent but You are adding that Image into another Panel!

```
Barco1.Parent = panel1;
```

So, Set the Background Color of the Panel1 as Transparent:

```
panel1.BackgroundColor=Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: I've tried this lines before, but it changes the origin point of the picture box, that without this line would be on the left of the panel but with that line it put it on the panel(which I really don't want) and also makes some weird when moving with the when running the programme