# Enabling Double Buffering

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, doublebuffered

I've seen the following code to enable double buffering on a winform:

```
// Activates double buffering 
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
   ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
   ControlStyles.UserPaint |
   ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.UpdateStyles();
```

Is this different in any way from simply setting Form.DoubleBuffering = true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Control.DoubleBuffering` performs

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, value);
```

so your code sets `ControlStyles.UserPaint` as well (which probably has no effect at this point).

Answer (score 2):

Setting a form's DoubleBuffering will set double buffering for that form. It's the same as calling

```
form.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, value);
```

The other flags like UserPaint and AllPaintingInWmPaint are styles that aren't set by simply setting control.DoubleBuffering = true

Answer (score 1):

In .NET 1.*x*, there was no `DoubleBuffered` property on controls, so `SetStyle` was the only way to enable it.  Code your see that uses `SetStyle` is probably either still around from 1.*x* days, or from developers who just haven't changed their habits since then.

Answer (score 1):

From [Stackoverflow: How to double buffer .NET controls on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form/77041#77041):

```
public static void SetDoubleBuffered(System.Windows.Forms.Control c)
{
   //Taxes: Remote Desktop Connection and painting
   //http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx
   if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
      return;

   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo aProp = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty(
        "DoubleBuffered",
         System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
   aProp.SetValue(c, true, null); 
}
```