# Custom edit control win32

Tags: c++, winapi, edit

I finally managed to  get my syntax highlighting done using richedit and iczelion's tutorials.
Now that i find it, it certainly is not fast enough. I am thinking of taking this one step ahead: a custom edit control. But i do not know how to go about it. Could you guys tell me how to go about it? Give me some info to start on? Maybe even some tutorial or suggest some book?

Now I'm not asking for you guys to spell it out for me, just something to start on. I will be using C++/ASM/Win32 API for this. I'm sure many of you have already made custom edit controls befores, so may be you could even share your experience.

Thanks,

Devjeet

Comment: [Visual Studio Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vcsamplesmfc) has a WordPad and SuperPad sample

Comment: Thanks, but actually im not looking for MFC tutorials.

Comment: A proper custom edit control is decidedly nontrivial, once you take non-English languages into account. I suggest that you reconsider.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to tell you that this is just kind of a side project for me and i took it up for educational purposes(kinda like learning assmebly, not to say that assembly has lost its usefullness). So I will not consider non-english languages to begin with. So keep that in mind. But yeah, even I'm concerned about the size. By big, how many lines do you mean? I haven't worked on a project that's more than 700 lines, so to speak

Comment: It could also be your code that is parsing the text on the fly in the edit control, which I assume is then outputting the RTF to the control.  For example, if you are parsing the entire text file on every key stroke as the user edits the source, then output all of the RTF to the control, it will be slow for larger files.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm parsing only the visible text. I let richedit do its drawing. Then I use DrawText to draw over the already painted text. So the problem is that there is a very slight, but highly noticeable flicker from black to the color with which i overwrite, when there are lots of words to be highlighted.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to double buffer richedit? Like when i call richedit to do its painting, it would paint to an back buffer and then i would draw my stuff on the back buffer, while preventing a redraw of the window this whole time, only when the whole process is complete would the screen be refreshed

Answer (score 12):

I spent one day on coding my own custom edit control - it's working well, so I would like to share my experience here, maybe for someone this code might be helpful... Because custom draw an common edit control is impossible ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955538/win32-how-to-custom-draw-an-edit-control)), you must write your own edit control. The general steps are:

```
// global vars
int select; // current selection position
int cursor; // current cursor position
HWND parent; // parent window
wchar_t buf[MAXINPUTBUF]; // edit buffer
WNDPROC oldproc; // old window procedure

// create custom control window
hWnd = CreateWindowW(L"static", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | SS_LEFT | SS_NOTIFY, 0, 0, 0, 0, parent, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(parent, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);

// todo: use SetProp() to store all global vars
oldproc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtrW(hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)InputWndProc);

SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOP, x, y, cx, cy, 0);
```

How to display keyboard input is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268(v=vs.85).aspx). My window procedure looks as follows

```
LRESULT CALLBACK InputWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        //SetFocus(hWnd);
        PostMessageW(GetParent(hWnd), WM_NEXTDLGCTL, (WPARAM)hWnd, TRUE);
        break;

    case WM_KILLFOCUS: 
        HideCaret(hWnd);
        DestroyCaret();
        break; 

    case WM_SETFOCUS:
        {
            RECT r;
            GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);
            // Create a solid black caret. 
            CreateCaret(hWnd, (HBITMAP) NULL, 2, r.bottom-r.top);

            ShowCaret(hWnd);
            InputWndRedraw(hWnd);

        }

        return FALSE;

    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
        return DLGC_WANTALLKEYS | DLGC_WANTARROWS;

    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    {
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case 'V':
            if (0x8000 & GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL))
            {
                HANDLE h;
                wchar_t *cb;
                int len,slen;

                InputWndDelete(hWnd);

                OpenClipboard(NULL);
                h = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);

                cb = (wchar_t*)GlobalLock(h);

                if (cb)
                {
                    memcpy(buf+(cursor+len)*sizeof(wchar_t), buf+cursor*sizeof(wchar_t), (slen-cursor)*sizeof(wchar_t));
                    memcpy(buf+cursor*sizeof(wchar_t), cb, len*sizeof(wchar_t));
                }

                GlobalUnlock(h);
                CloseClipboard();
                InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
            }
            break;

        case VK_RIGHT:

                if (cursor-1 >= MAXINPUTBUF || cursor >= (int)wcslen(buf))
                    break;

                cursor++;

                if (!(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000))
                    select = cursor;

                InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
                break;

            case VK_TAB:
                PostMessageW(GetParent(hWnd), WM_NEXTDLGCTL, GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000, FALSE);
                break;

            case VK_LEFT:
                if (cursor <= 0)
                    break;

                cursor--;

                if (!(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000))
                    select = cursor;

                InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
                break;

            case VK_HOME:
                cursor = 0;

                if (!(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000))
                    select = cursor;

                InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
                break;

            case VK_END:
                cursor = wcslen(buf);

                if (!(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000))
                    select = cursor;

                InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
                break;

            case VK_DELETE:
                if (cursor >= (int)wcslen(buf))
                {
                    InputWndDelete(hWnd);
                    InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
                    break;
                }

                if (select == cursor)
                    select ++;

                InputWndDelete(hWnd);
                InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
            break;

            case VK_BACK:

                if (cursor <= 0)
                {
                    InputWndDelete(hWnd);
                    InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
                    break;
                }


                if (select == cursor)
                    cursor --;


                InputWndDelete(hWnd);
                InputWndRedraw(hWnd);
            }

        }
        break;

    case WM_CHAR: 
        if (wParam < VK_SPACE)
        break;


        InputWndDelete(hWnd);

        if (wcslen(buf)+1 < MAXINPUTBUF)
        {
            wmemmove(buf+(cursor+1)*sizeof(wchar_t), buf+cursor*sizeof(wchar_t), wcslen(s->buf)-cursor);
            buf[cursor] = wParam;
            cursor++;
            select = cursor;
        }

        InputWndRedraw(hWnd);

        break;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        // no flickering
        return TRUE;

    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            HDC dc;
            PAINTSTRUCT paint;

            dc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &paint);
            InputWndDraw(hWnd, dc);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &paint);

        }
        return TRUE;

    }

    return CallWindowProcW(oldproc, hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Delete current selected text (from *select* to *cursor*).

```
void InputWndDelete(HWND hWnd)
{
    int len;

    len = wcslen(buf);

    if (select > cursor)
    {
        memcpy(buf+cursor*sizeof(wchar_t), buf+select*sizeof(wchar_t), (len - select)*sizeof(wchar_t));
        ZeroMemory(buf+(len-select+cursor)*sizeof(wchar_t), (MAXINPUTBUF-len+select-cursor)*sizeof(wchar_t));
        select = cursor;
    }
    else if (select < cursor)
    {
        memcpy(buf+select*sizeof(wchar_t), buf+cursor*sizeof(wchar_t), (len - cursor)*sizeof(wchar_t));
        ZeroMemory(buf+(len-cursor+select)*sizeof(wchar_t), (MAXINPUTBUF-len+cursor-select)*sizeof(wchar_t));
        cursor = select;
    }
    else
    {
        select = cursor;
    }
}
```

Draw window on window DC

```
void InputWndRedraw(HWND hWnd)
{
    HDC hdc;

    HideCaret(hWnd); 

    hdc = GetDC(hWnd); 
    InputWndDraw(hWnd, hdc);
    ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc); 

    ShowCaret(hWnd); 

}
```

Draw input buffer (buf*) on device context. Syntax highlighting and other formatting features goes here...

```
void InputWndDraw(HWND hWnd, HDC hdc)
{
    RECT r,cr;

    GetClientRect(hWnd, &cr);

    // draw selected rectangle FillRect()...

    CopyRect(&r,&cr);
    DrawTextW(hdc, buf, -1, &r, DT_LEFT | DT_TOP);


    if (cursor)
        DrawTextW(hdc, buf, cursor, &r, DT_LEFT | DT_TOP | DT_CALCRECT);
    else
        r.right = cr.left;

    if (GetFocus() == hWnd)
    {
        if (r.right > cr.right)
            SetCaretPos(cr.right, cr.top); 
        else
            SetCaretPos(r.right, cr.top); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Great post! There are several approaches to [customizing controls according to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/user-controls-intro). You are using traditional [subclassing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/subclassing-overview) and that page also provides a new approach by SetWindowSubclass.