# Avoid Flickering in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, buffer

Double buffering not working with combo-box.
is there any another methods to avoid flickering in windows forms?

i have one windows form with number of panels in it. I'm showing only one panel at a time based on my menu selection.

i have one icon panel,one header panel and the combo box. based on the selected item of that combo-box the gridview1 and 2 are filling. when I'm rapidly selecting the combo-box item using my keyboard down arrow the icon panel and the header panel are always repainting. i need to keep that both without any change. this two panels producing some flashing effect(ie,they are blinking or flashing) while I'm changing the combo box selected index. is there any way to avoid this flashing.? i tried double-buffered enabled in form constructor and form load event.

Please Help.

```
InitializeComponent();

this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, false);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, false);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
```

I've tried this code in form constructor and form load event.

Comment: It's all irrelevant .. USE this custom control from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362988/treeview-flickering][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362988/treeview-flickering

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yet another solution:

```
//TODO: Don't forget to include using System.Runtime.InteropServices.

internal static class NativeWinAPI
{
    internal static readonly int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    internal static readonly int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    internal static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    internal static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
}
```

And your form constructor should look as follows:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    int style = NativeWinAPI.GetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE);
    style |= NativeWinAPI.WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
    NativeWinAPI.SetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE, style);
}
```

In the code above, you might change `this.Handle` to something like `MyFlickeringPanel.Handle`

You can read a bit more about it here: [Extended Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and here: [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> With WS_EX_COMPOSITED set, all descendants of a window get
>   bottom-to-top painting order using double-buffering. Bottom-to-top
>   painting order allows a descendent window to have translucency (alpha)
>   and transparency (color-key) effects, but only if the descendent
>   window also has the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT bit set. Double-buffering allows
>   the window and its descendents to be painted without flicker.

Comment: I don't have much more reputation to up-vote the answer.. that's why I'm not up-voting... Sorry............

Comment: @Khil I had this problem and this worked so well. My app was flickering badly so I tried this and then no flickering. Then what I did notice is that every other window on this machine was doing it also. I didn't notice this at first because I was concentrating on my app. I still do not know why every window on this machine is flickering, but I do know that my app is the only one that isn't :)

Comment: Plus1 for `MyFlickeringPanel.Handle`

Comment: Thanks for `MyFlickeringPanel.Handle`

Answer (score 4):

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams handleParam = base.CreateParams;
            handleParam.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;   // WS_EX_COMPOSITED       
            return handleParam;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution #1:**
Use `ComboxBox.BeginUpdate()` before you add items. This will prevent the `Control` from repainting the `ComboBox` each time an item is added to the list. After adding the items, you can use `ComboBox.EndUpdate()` to repaint.

**Solution #2**

```
private void EnableDoubleBuffering()
{
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
}
```

Comment: `EnableDoubleBuffering()` should be called in Page_load or New() ?