# Is it possible to set TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER without using p/invoke?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to reduce flickering in my TreeView control by using double buffering. Using the recommendations outlined here seems to work, which sets the TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER extended window style available since Vista:
[Treeview flickering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362988/treeview-flickering)

However, I would much prefer not to have the extra dependency on user32.dll as the project is set to also run on Mono. Is it somehow possible to set the TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER extended window style without using P/Invoke?

I had hoped I could use CreateParams to do it, but it didn't seem to work. Here's what I tried:

```
const int TVS_NOHSCROLL = 0x8000;
const int TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER = 0x0004;

protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        var parameters = base.CreateParams;
        parameters.Style |= TVS_NOHSCROLL;
        parameters.ExStyle |= TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER;
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

The TVS_NOHSCROLL is just to demonstrate setting a window style using CreateParams which does work. According to the documentation, you can use ExStyle to set extended window styles, but unfortunately this does not seem to work for TreeView.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's not possible, TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE is **required**.  Avoiding a dependency on user32.dll make no sense, it is one of the core Windows operating system DLLs.  TreeView itself requires it.

Comment: I understand that it is a totally acceptable solution on Windows. However, when using Windows Forms under Mono, you can't P/Invoke native system libraries. They have reimplemented TreeView using some other backend.

Comment: I somehow already feared there was no other way around it... I just don't get then why CreateParams.ExStyle doesn't work. I've seen other non-TreeView sample code pass all manner of extended styles from buttons to listviews, and it seems even from the official documentation to be the right place to do it. Oh well...

Answer (score -2):

Double buffering in .NET Windows Forms controls can be set by the property of the same name:

```
yourControl.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

You can use the `SetStyle` method of the control to set additional styles.

Comment: This is an entirely different kind of double-buffering, Winforms is not involved with it.

Comment: This definitely doesn't work on TreeView. It was the first thing I tried; no effect and it even looks like they've gone to some lengths to avoid having people use it since the property is hidden even to derived classes.