# Sliding a bitmap on the screen smoothly C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bitmap

I have a form similar to an android notification drawer type thing, users have an option to put a background image on the form; since the form opens up all the way by pulling it on to the screen with a mouse, how can I make the bitmap look like its not drawing while it is being pulled on to the screen? I am using C#.net.  As the form is pulled up, the bitmap is white until it has a second to load.

Comment: Can you put some code?It is hard to tell what you want to do from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting your form to paint in Double-buffered mode.

```
class Form1 : Form {
  Form1(){
   this.doublebuffered = true;
  }
}
```

[How to double buffer .NET controls on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form)