# Improve performance when resizing a Form with a Hi-Res background image

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, resize, paintevent

I have a **Winforms** with some controls and the main form has a big picture as background with a `BackgroundImageLayout` property `Stretched` enabled.

> The main problem is that the resize operation turns slowly because the
>   background image.

The problem is that resizing a Winforms which has a picture and Stretched BackgroundImageLayout property is a nightmare! it begins slow and all the controls are flickering when resizing the form.

I've tried to reduce the image size but I can't reduce it more to don't loose image quality.

I've tried also to do something like this but doesn't reduced the annoying effect:

```
Private Sub Main_ResizeBegin(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeBegin

    GroupBox_Genres.SuspendLayout()
    GroupBox_Options.SuspendLayout()
    ListBox_Genres.SuspendLayout()
    ListView_Elektro1.SuspendLayout()

    Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None
    Me.SuspendLayout()

End Sub

Private Sub Main_ResizeEnd(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ResizeEnd

    GroupBox_Genres.ResumeLayout()
    GroupBox_Options.ResumeLayout()
    ListBox_Genres.ResumeLayout()
    ListView_Elektro1.ResumeLayout()
    Me.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
    Me.ResumeLayout()

End Sub
```

Any ideas of how to resolve the slow and annoying effects of resizing a winforms with a big picture as background?.

> EDIT

For take an idea of my problem the application is this:

[image]

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form) post.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå My form is already double buffered but still slow when resizing the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code in your form to avoid form flickering which also avoids your image flickering. you don't need to resize the image you are using.

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H2000000
        Return cp
    End Get
End Property
```

This will paint the controls in your form and brings the form visible after all controls loaded and avoids the flickering.

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to improve the performance, not to loose it, I did time ago a lot of performance tests with that "anti-flickering magic code" and turns the application around 30% more slow when using that, thankyou anyways, really flickering is not my problem now, the resize operation turns slow because the background image that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Can you explain the code a bit.? What's the actual flow of this code.? when will this particular piece of code get invoked.? To which, the variable `cp` will be returned.? It'll be helpful for me as well as others, if you give some explanations. Thanks.

Comment: this would not speed up the control painting but it will hold the screen for a while and just show the updated screen instead of flickering