# Flickering issue in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-controls, flicker

I have a problem with flickering on my controls. I have Drag and drop operation, and when dragging a control, it is flickering. How can I solve it ? I tried this

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        .
        .
        .
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
```

But did not worked for me. How can I fix it ?

Comment: What kind of controls are flickering?  You included a user-controls tag.  Your DoubleBuffered setting is only for the form, not the controls.

Comment: My controls are Panels LarsTech

Comment: See [How to double buffer .NET controls on a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/76993/719186)

Comment: Thanks. I saw the answer for that questions was this http://stackoverflow.com/a/77233/1699916  now a question, what is  SetDoubleBuffered ? is it an event or just method ? if method where it have to be called ?

Comment: It's a method you call in your form's constructor or OnLoad method (Load event).

Comment: all Right, worked Lars :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void SetDoubleBuffered(System.Windows.Forms.Control c)
{
   //Taxes: Remote Desktop Connection and painting
   //http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2006/01/03/508694.aspx
   if (System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession)
      return;

   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo aProp = 
         typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty(
               "DoubleBuffered", 
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

   aProp.SetValue(c, true, null); 
}
```

This method helps a lot.

was took from here

[stackoverflow.com/a/77233/1699916](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233/1699916)

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers here.  If this worked for you then your question should be closed as a duplicate.