# .Net controls show ghost menu items; double buffering doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance

I have a winforms application with a menu. The "New" item on the menu creates a new control which has a lot of sub-controls, so it takes about 300ms to construct the control.

When you click the "New" menu item, you see something like this for a brief moment:

[image]

As you can see, the menu disappears over some of the form, but over the toolbar, for example, you can still see it.

I tried this solution [How to double buffer .NET controls on a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form), but it caused more problems than it solved (Laggy menus, crashes when window is not maximized).

Comment: it might because the program uses too many GDI resources. Please use process explorer(http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to see how much GDI handles the process is using.

Comment: 299 GDI handles according to process explorer. Is that a lot or a little?

Comment: The number is OK, not too much.