# How to make a horizontal bar in a panel control when drawing on it?

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, panel

I have a panel and I need to draw a horizontal chart on it. But sometimes the chart can be too long for the panel, even the form has maximum size. So I want to make a horizontal bar on panel to enable the user to see the remaining part of the drawing that is out of the bounds.

**Chart is something like this:**

[image]

As you can see, the chart is out of the panel's bounds and form's too. I don't have any idea how can it be done, so I have no code to show. So how can I do it using a basic method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the solution is pretty basic, as long as the size you want to draw won't go over 32k pixels width:

- Put your `Panel` inside another one.
- The **outer** `Panel` has `AutoScroll=true`
- The **inner** one where you draw  has the size of your drawing.
- You need to draw in the `Paint` event, as you should anyway (!)

Now the outer `Panel` shows a horizontal scrollbar and the user can scroll right and left and see all parts of the drawing..

One alternative would be to add a dummy control that enforces the `AutoScroll` of your drawing `Panel` to work, but I find using two `Panels` the cleaner way to go..

Note: You should either use a `PictureBox` or at least a double-buffered `Panel` subclass to avoid flicker and tearing:

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
{
    public DrawPanel()
    { DoubleBuffered = true; }
}
```

---

**Update:** Instead of a `Panel`, which is a `Container` control and not really meant to draw onto you can use a `Picturebox` or a `Label` (with `Autosize=false`); both have the `DoubleBuffered` property turned on out of the box and support drawing better than `Panels` do.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks @TaW. Additionally I solved double buffer problem from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form

Comment: Glad to help. Nice chart btw..!