# C# Windows Form application mdi child form rendering takes too much time

Tags: c#, winforms, performance

I'm having multiple gridview in my form and one of gridview rows is painted based on data.

[image]

But it looks weird when I load the form, it's like controls not having proper rendering on form.

Please look [at this video](https://streamable.com/q3rr7) for better understanding:

Comment: If possible, can u switch to a `DatagridView`?

Comment: I'm using datagridview only. :)

Comment: what is the problem? What looks weird?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler please see video i've mentioned in link.

Comment: I see *(or better to say I think I see)* only a single error on the video, This error I see on rendering of almost all elements of all application taht use a Intel CPU build in graphics card. Until I changed my (home and work) computer to use a Intel build-in graphics card, I did not see this error *(or at least, it was very rare)*. Now I see this "duplication of displayed data" on LibreOffice, Opera, Chrome, Firefox, everywhere (when scrolling).

Comment: @Julo So did you mean that there nothing we can do with windows application, right? I'm confused!

Comment: Show your loading code, not your pictures.

Comment: @NiravParsana, if this 'effect' is all the time, the it is probably something different. The problem I have seen is (as far as I know) limited to HW *(probably drivers)* and has not 100 % probability. In this case, there is a chance that you can do something with it. Try invalidate the area, to request redraw. When it is the error I have describe, it should change when the controls are redrawn *(e.g. mouse over effect should change the state, when you browse mouse over controls)*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/89125/17034

Comment: @HansPassant I've found your solution working. 
It keeps UI thread busy for sometime but still far better than previous results. 
Very Impressed! Thank You :)

Comment: If a question relies on a "see video" link then it is off-topic, since when the video is moved/deleted, the question will not be useful to future readers. Please convert that to an embeddable GIF, or show the problem in still images instead.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: To me it looks like your UI is stretched and positioned according to the DataGridViews. When your form loads, it tries to place the controls, but keeps shifting them around as each added row in your DataGridView changes the whole UI? Try disabling the queries temporarely  and see how the UI behaves. Add a button to test executing the queries After the UI has loaded, if it makes a difference. I'd also try fixed sizes and positions to controls if nothing else helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the video what I could understand is it is taking time to Load,

If you have written the ADO.NET(to get data from DB) on Load Method, it will take a moment to fetch and display them.

I would advise you to use individual threads(for each Grid) to fetch data during the Load, to Optimize the performance.

Comment: I measured time too. Form Load event function takes 2500-2700 ms. but can't figure out reason of that weird loading effect. :/

Comment: From my experience, it also depends on the configuration of machine

Comment: The datagridview control is made to handle millions of rows of data easily...I don't see a logic behind the machine configuration tho :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem entirely but here are some tips/tricks :

! . If you are updating the `Datagridview` source, try setting `AutoSizeColumnsMode` to none before updating the datasource.This has been proven to work.

2 . There's a property called `DoubleBuffer`.I am not gonna dig into the description of it but in easy words , it will help u to improve your performance significantly :)

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
public void DoubleBuffered(DataGridView dgv, bool setting)
{
    Type dgvType = dgv.GetType();
    PropertyInfo pi = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, null);
}
}
  ExtensionMethods.DoubleBuffered(mydgvw, True);
```

3 . Last but not the least, when displaying data in dgvw from a datasource, sometimes it is helpful to use collections like `ObserveableCollection` or if possible,try to reduce the amount of displayed data through filtering.

4 . Using a `DataReader` over a `DataAdapter` is significantly faster.Create a class to manage your data,use a `DataReader` instead of a `DataAdapter`/`DataTable`. E.g.

```
 public class Employees
{
    private int age;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return age; }
        set { age = value; }
    }
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
       } 
    }

  ///create an array

 ArrayList myData = new ArrayList();

 ///Now,let ur datareader do the job for you .

 while (reader.Read())
           {
               Employees emp = new Employees();
               emp.Id = (int)reader[0];
               emp.Name = reader[1].ToString();
               emp.Age = (int)reader[2];
               myData.Add(m);
           }
           dataGridView1.DataSource = myData;
```

4 . Another best bet is,if u use a `Datareader` and follow the above code,make sure to run it in the background on the main form load, then on button clicks , just set the `dataGridView.DataSource` to the array....

These are the basics but hope they'll help you :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but sadly i don't see it working. Still the same issue.

Comment: i don't really see any issue in ur video...can u explain a bit ?

Comment: Did you notice when i click on 'Lessons', how much time it takes to show the form and once form starts loading, one by one controls appears.

Comment: If u are using a datatable,that is a bad choice,are u using it ?

Comment: Yes, that's where i load data from database

Comment: @NiravParsana there is still one more thing you can do, to speed up 'loading'. You can disable control rendering when data are changed. I'm not so sure how this function is used/activated in C# *(perhaps `SuspendLayout`)*, but I saw this function used few years ago in Borland. Sorry I newer really did research this in C#, but as from my experience, GUI rendering in C# is slow, when many controls are used *(tested on form with 120+ controls, mostly check boxes and radio buttons)*. And one more, updating `DataGird` *(or similar control)* with more than 1000 elements took about a 5 seconds.

Comment: Using a datareater over a dataadpter is significantly faster... I will update my answer :)

Comment: @zackraiyan Thanks for all the solution. I've implemented some of them as I've too complex code to work with. So, I can't apply all of them but solution provided by you and HansPassant helped me to reduce issue.

Comment: Please mark the answer as answer and uovite it if ti helped